# Show that a language is not regular using the Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Given a language $L = \{a^pb^{2p} \mid p \ge 1\}$, how could I show, using the Pumping Lemma that $L$ is not regular?

Comment: This is a fairly standard exercise -- it appears in both computability texts I have.  Is it homework?  Do you understand how to make use of the pumping lemma?

Comment: It is part of an exercise list to help people study for the exam. And no, I don't know exactly how to make use of the pumping lemma :)

Comment: check http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/157

Comment: Without further detail -- your attempt and a specific question -- this is question does not ask for more than the [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/157). Please check there; if you continue to have problems, you can edit the question accordingly and flag for reopening.